# Increasing Sample Size for Symbology with arcpy.mp and CIM

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, cartographic-information-model

I am closing in on finishing a script for some map production in ArcGIS Pro 2.9 and one of my last steps is to increase the sample size of the layer being symbolized, then apply a color ramp, and render. I can apply the color ramp symbology, but I am running into an issue where I cannot increase the sample size of features and then render using the new sample size. The default sample size is 10,000 and on average I have about 100,000 plus segments I want to apply the symbology to.

For reference: To do this in ArcGIS Pro without scripting in python you would, first, change the symbology to "Graduated Colors", then go into the "Advanced Symbology Options", and then open "Sample Size" and change the maximum sample size to something greater than the default (10,000). Screenshot below of the sample size being changed.

I've looked around and have not found any promising solutions. I found a [post](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/accessing-advanced-symbology-with-python-sample/m-p/1051468) that suggested I modify the layer properties for sample size using CIM. Initially, I thought this was promising, but upon opening the map, after the code executed the sample size did not increase and the render is incomplete (See screen shot below of the black circle of features not rendered).

Here is a snippet of my code, where I apply the color ramp and change the layer definition via CIM.

```
# set map project
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(os.path.join(Name_path, "{}.aprx".format(Name)))
# add layer to map prjoect
Rds_Lyr_ForSym = aprxMap.addDataFromPath(RoadsLayer_Path)

# Set Symbology
RdsSym = Rds_Lyr_ForSym.symbology

    if hasattr(RdsSym, 'renderer'):
        if RdsSym.renderer.type == "SimpleRenderer":
            RdsSym.updateRenderer('GraduatedColorsRenderer')

            # This is the modificiation of the CIM
            lcim = Rds_Lyr_ForSym.getDefinition('V2')
            lcim.renderer.sampleSize = 1000000
            Rds_Lyr_ForSym.setDefinition(lcim)

            # Goes on to render the color ramp
            RdsSym.renderer.classificationField = "NEAR_DIST"
            RdsSym.renderer.breakCount = 100
            RdsSym.renderer.colorRamp = aprx.listColorRamps('Cyan to Purple')[0]

            # Apply Symoblogy
            Rds_Lyr_ForSym.symbology = RdsSym
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are experiencing is a chicken 'n' egg scenario. How can you update a symbology with a new sample size so the class breaks adjust if the class breaks don't already exist?

The following code adjusts the sample size using CIM but for that to work it creates the class breaks first, think of that laying out the framework. Then you adjust sample size and then re-run the setup of the renderer so the appropriate events fire to generate the class breaks based upon your new sample size.

```py
import arcpy

# Get the layer
myPrj = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('current')
myMap = myPrj.listMaps("Layers")[0]
l = myMap.listLayers("Priority Habitat Inventory")[0]

# Initialise renderer and save back to layer
sym = l.symbology
sym.updateRenderer ('GraduatedColorsRenderer')
sym.renderer.classificationField = "Area_Ha"
sym.renderer.breakCount = 5
l.symbology = sym

# Change sample size using CIM
lcim = l.getDefinition('V2')
lcim.renderer.sampleSize = 10
l.setDefinition(lcim)

# re-run set up of renderer to run the computation of break values 
# now limited by sample size then save back
sym = l.symbology
sym.updateRenderer ('GraduatedColorsRenderer')
sym.renderer.classificationField = "Area_Ha"
sym.renderer.breakCount = 5
l.symbology = sym
```

Comment: Tried this out and I am still getting the default of 10000 as a sample size after the code has run through. When you ran this, did you run it in the arcpro python console? I'm running my outside console/IDE, pycharm, and am getting no luck.

Comment: Yes I ran it in the console, are you saving your map document?

Comment: Yes, technically using a template, saving the template as a copy (to use to symbolize layers), then symbolizing, and saving again.

Answer (score 0):

The script below works on graduated colors symbology in ArcGIS. I guess with some modification it should work in Pro.

Before (with 10000 sample size):

[image]

After (207k records):

[image]

Script:

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "ABCD")[0]
symb=lyr.symbology
theField = symb.valueField
allValues = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(lyr,theField)
aRange=np.linspace(0, 100, num=11)
breakValues = np.percentile(allValues[theField], aRange)
lyr.symbology.classBreakValues=breakValues
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: When I get to work tomorrow, I'll run it with the format to go with pro.

Comment: So it did require some modification to match syntax for pro but even after running it is still to working when I run the script with an IDE.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your message. Does it take too long?

Comment: So I had to modify the code you provided above to work within ArcPro (slight modification of how the map document comes in), but even with the modification, the sample size did not increase. I am running this code in an IDE because the process has several other geoprocessing steps and creating other items. I am wondering if running this code in the IDE is the issue.